# Retrieve instagram user email address

Tags: ios, instagram-api

I have read the instagram developer docs and tried this most possible endpoint which is

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/user-id?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
>
> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

I can get the result however there is no email address returned. Is there a hack that can bypass this endpoints to get instagram email address?

I'm needing this for instagram login and registration.. TIA

Answer (score 4):

**NO, it is not possible** in Instagram. The API **do not** return the user email in always.

**example**

**Request URL**

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

the output **Response**

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "1574083",
    "username": "snoopdogg",
    "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
    "bio": "This is my bio",
    "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
    "counts": {
        "media": 1320,
        "follows": 420,
        "followed_by": 3410
    }
}
```

for more [information](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users)

Comment: I think I have mention this already. I am only asking if there is a way. I'm not asking how to do it with that endpoint

Comment: there is no other way bro,